# Localization of a infinite sum of ideals not equal to infinite sum of localized ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, localization

I'm trying to find a counterexample to
$$
S^{-1} \left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty I_i \right) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty S^{-1}I_i,
$$

where the $I_i$ are ideals on a commutative ring $A$ and $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$.

The person that suggested this problem to me gave a hint that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty I_i$ should be a large set, but with each $S^{-1}I_i$ small. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Does the ring need to be Noetherian?

Comment: @walkar I don't think it's necessary

Comment: Have you tried to prove that the equality holds? What did not work?

Comment: Definitely do spend some time trying to prove the equality.  That there are infinitely many ideals involved in the sum does not matter; any element is contained in a finite sum.

Comment: For any ring homomorphism, extension of ideals commutes with arbitrary sums. Perhaps, you meant the infinite intersection instead of the infinite sum, right?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I might be wrong, but I'm certain it was meant for the sum... in the case of the intersection (Localization of intersection of infinite ideals equals the intersection of the localization of said infinite ideals) the result is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find a counterexample because the equality always holds.  Do you know the proof when the sum is finite? The proof in the infinite case is effectively identical.

Comment: I do know the proof when the sum is finite. Are you telling me I've been bamboozled? :O

Comment: @Mand You have been bamboozled... But don't take my word for it, write out the proof! And show it to your friend :P

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's simply showing that each element of the left hand side is on the right hand and vice versa, right? Will do!

Comment: @BadamBaplan Hi! Do you have a reference for the proof when the sum is finite?